# Different locking behaviour for first and consequent update statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say that I have 2 tables: `activities` and `profiles` and `activities` have a foreign key `profile_id` and a constraint for that key.

Now, if go to `psql`, start a transaction and update some random activitity:

```
begin;

update activities set read = false where id = 1;
```

I get the following locks:

```
# SELECT locktype, relation::regclass, mode FROM pg_locks;

     locktype    |             relation             |       mode
---------------+----------------------------------+------------------
 relation      | pg_locks                         | AccessShareLock
 relation      | activities_profile_id_type_index | RowExclusiveLock
 relation      | activities_pkey                  | RowExclusiveLock
 relation      | activities                       | RowExclusiveLock
 virtualxid    |                                  | ExclusiveLock
 transactionid |                                  | ExclusiveLock
```

but then if I execute exactly the same query again, the picture changes to this:

```
   locktype    |             relation             |       mode
---------------+----------------------------------+------------------
 relation      | profiles_username_index          | AccessShareLock
 relation      | profiles_user_id_index           | AccessShareLock
 relation      | profiles_pkey                    | AccessShareLock
 relation      | profiles                         | RowShareLock
 relation      | pg_locks                         | AccessShareLock
 relation      | activities_profile_id_type_index | RowExclusiveLock
 relation      | activities_pkey                  | RowExclusiveLock
 relation      | activities                       | RowExclusiveLock
 virtualxid    |                                  | ExclusiveLock
 transactionid |                                  | ExclusiveLock
```

So after the second update, we see that we have some locks on the parent table which we didn't have after the first update.

So my question is why it is different for the second query and why it is required to check the parent table if we don't update any foreign keys on the child row?

EDIT: Postgresql version 9.6

Comment: did you commit the first update?

Comment: @PeterRing No, no commits